# python login to website, no "id" only "class" for login button

Tags: python, python-3.x, form-submit

Have been searching and searching, testing and trying, reading and reading... I am not a programmer, and do not pick these things up quickly.

here is my code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://company.page.com/member/index.php' (this url has the form on it)
values = {'username': 'myusernamehere',
          'password': 'mypasswordhere'}

r = requests.post(url, data=values)

# Now you have logged in
url = "http://company.page.com/member/member.php" (this is the resulting url after logging in)

# sending cookies as well
result = requests.get(url, cookies=r.cookies)

print (result.headers)
print (result.text)
```

I get error:

```
<form action="http://company.page.com/member/index.php" method="post" id="login">
   <h3 class="head">Donor Login</h3>
   <em class="notice"><p class="errors">you must log in</p><br />
```

Image of website source code: (first way i could figure out how to post html)

[image: website sourcecode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects). Or cookies are not kept.

```
import requests

s = requests.session() # <--

url = 'http://company.page.com/member/index.php'
values = {'username': 'myusernamehere',
          'password': 'mypasswordhere'}

r = s.post(url, data=values) # session.post instead of requests.post

# Now you have logged in
url = "http://company.page.com/member/member.php" (this is the resulting url after logging in)

result = s.get(url) # Use session.get and do not specify cookies.

print (result.headers)
print (result.text)
```

Comment: gladly and up arrowed it as well!  You rock!

Comment: do you have any experience with "kivy", i want to make my python code as an android app.. .apk

Comment: @xopenex, I don't know *kivy*.